# configuration CI/CD pipeline on Azure with Powershell Script

Tags: git, azure, powershell

I'm doing configuration CI/CD pipeline to publish SSRS and PowerBI reports to Azure with using Powershell on stages. I'm stuck on how to write code to get changed files on the branch, from there change the connection string to the database and then publish to dev workspace. I got complicated and confuses on the first step that get changed files from pull request approved. I try usinng git to get the changed files, but it seem i wrong. please help me find the ways to solve it. The code below:

```
# Write your PowerShell commands here.

Write-Host "Hello World"
$Path = $env:AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY
$PBIX = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | where {$_.Extension -eq ".pbix"} 
foreach ($File in $PBIX )
{
   Write-Host "File changed: $($File.BaseName)"
}
$files= $(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~2)
    Write-Host "Found $($files) changed files"
```

The reuslts:

```
-all name files printed.
could not access HEAD
PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement the same workflow. I highly recommend using the **Power BI Actions** extension. It's free and requires just a few configurations.

You first have to create an App registration with the following permissions
[image]

Create a new connection to Power BI service

[image]

Allow service principals to use Power BI APIs

[image]

And you are done. The pipelines will be:

**Build:**

```
trigger:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**.pbix'
    TargetFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'PowerBIArtifact'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

**Release:**
[image]

**References:**

- Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-power-bi-actions
- Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWM2wbwntCQ

Answer (score 0):

Reg the error about **could not access HEAD** there are 2 possible cause for this.

- Your Script task doesn't have proper permission, check the [Allow scripts to access the system token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#allow-scripts-to-access-the-system-token) is enabled

[image]

- [Your pipeline itself having some issues with your repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

> Azure Pipelines must be granted access to your repositories to trigger
> their builds and fetch their code during builds. Normally, a pipeline
> has access to repositories in the same project. But, if you wish to
> access repositories in a different project, then you need to update
> the permissions granted to job access tokens.

Adding to @IvanPorta answer, if you want to more control to your cicd, you can use the way I explained it in [PowerBI - CICD using Azure DevOps](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/PowerBI-CICD-using-Azure-DevOps/ba-p/769244)

Github Code for the Powershell: https://github.com/jayendranarumugam/PowerBI-CICD
YouTube Explaination: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAeypbT6Gj0